# Adding multiple boxes in one page and saving the info from each box

Tags: php, javascript

I have this task - to make a simple CMS where one of the abilities should be to create a page and add as many boxes as the admin would like and then to have the ability to edit each one of them using ckeditor, and ofcourse the page should be visible in the frontend.

For now I'm just using CodeIgniter trying to keep things simple but for this task I can't think of pure PHP solution. I'm not much into JS and it's libraries/frameworks so what do you think is the solution with the smallest learning curve? I can't invest too much time in this, so I'm searching for an easy to implement solution (if there is such)?

Comment: you may echo as many echo as many as boxes you want, and you may save them in array of each individual field

Comment: i don't want to sound harsh, but i might don't understand well your question. If you don't want to spend much time on this, why not to use one of the many CMS out there?

Comment: It's a task given to me, it's part from a bigger problem but this is what gives me trouble. As I said I'm not much into JS, I've been working mostly with ExtJS and for example if it's too complex to do it with something like jQuery then I won't bother at all and just start to learn some JS library, but if it's something easy to implement then I want to try.